# jQuery pass function parameter to nested function

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

I have the following in jquery:

```
$( ".paid" ).each(function (i, tag) {
    $(tag).change(function (i, tag) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert($(tag).i);
            $("invdesc_" + i).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    })
});
```

How can i pass `i` in the $(".paid") function to the $(tag).change function?

I need to change the `.prop()` based on the key which is coming from a php foreach() iteration.

Comment: change the arguments  $(tag).change(function (j, tag1)

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Can you provide same HTML as there will certainly be a much simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
$(".paid").each(function(i, tag) {
    $(tag).change({ index: i, elem: tag }, function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert($(e.data.elem)); // tag
            $("invdesc_" + e.data.index).prop("disabled", false); // i
        }
    })
});
```

You can pass the `eventData` any object and retrieve it through [**`event.data`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.data)